# How to change email addrsses that Facebook or YouTube create for mobile publishing?

Tags: facebook, youtube, email

How to modify Facebook mobile upload email address or YouTube to another easy to remember email address. The email addresses that they generate for me are like these samples: `jaksdflaksdfl@m.youtube.com` or `laskdfjjasdfk@m.facebook.com`.

I publish my videos and images by them and I don't want the random email addresses that they create for me.

Comment: i know that emails created with randomize string because others cant guess emails for sending instead of me. but when only me with my email can send attachment for uploading then we should modify this random email

Comment: This feature no longer exists on YouTube, no idea about facebook though.